# User regular expression to match filename and slice it in pieces

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
./../../../project-files/files/RE-filename.docx
```

And I want to receive an array with two elements: `RE-filename` and `docx`. By the way, the `RE-filename` section could contain a German umlaut (äöü).

I use the following pattern with `preg_match_all()`:

```
\/(?!.+\/)|\\(?!.+\\)(.+)-(?!.+-)(.+)\.(?!.*\.)(.+)
```

However, it doesnt do what I expect. It works when I don't use `|\\(?!.+\\)` but I am scared that the script will run on a different system that uses `\` to separate the directories, that's why I wanted to test for both.

Any ideas? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to use this complicated regex? Wouldn't `pathinfo()` be sufficient? It can also get the filename without extension and the extension separately. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Oh, didn't know this function. Thanks

Comment: also, protip: never, ever, let users get files that aren't in your server's static asset dir. Because nothing's stopping someone from trying to get into your windows dir or grab your password file, and that's about as insecure as you can get. Only accept "relative" content paths, and append those to your know static or user content dir, and if that doesn't resolve to a file, too bad: return a 404. (bonus points for not checking the filesystem, but checking your content table in your database, so people can't fish for files that exist, but aren't known to your content table)